# Databinding, using formulas for unusual binding possible?

Tags: c#, wpf

**Edit:** I marked an answer, since it did bring me on the right track. The only issue left seems to be a design thing and according to the boardrules should be asked as a seperate question. See my followup question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744475/design-issue-how-to-approach-this-specific-task **Thanks for your help here!**

I am trying to bind a list of custom objects to a DataGrid. Straight binding seems easy enough, but i need to specify some complex formulas for some extra fields that do not directly show up in my class. Also i want to be able to EDIT the data in the Grid and get updates on related fields. Let me show you an example, because it is really hard to explain. I will simplify it to rooms with items. Each item can be red and blue.

My Class looks like this:

```
public class room
{
   public string strRoomName { set; get; }
   public string strItemname { set; get; }
   public int intRedItem { set; get; }
   public int intBlueItem { set; get; }
}
```

Now if i use dataTable.ItemSource = myList; i get something like this:

```
nr. | room | name | red | blue

1. living room, ball, 2, 1
2. sleeping room, bunny, 4, 1
3. living room, chair, 3, 2
4. kitchen, ball, 4, 7
5. garage, chair, 1, 4
```

Now for the complex part i need help with. I want every item to be the same number, red and blue. And because this does not hold true i want to see the "inbalance" per room AND globally like this:

```
nr. | room | name | red | blue | missing | global red | global blue | global missing 

1. living room, ball, 2, 1, 1 blue, 6, 7, 1 red
2. sleeping room, bunny, 4, 1, 3 blue, 4, 1, 3 blue
3. living room, chair, 3, 2, 1 blue, 4, 6, 2 red 
4. kitchen, ball, 4, 7, 3 red, 6, 7, 1 red
5. garage, chair, 1, 4, 3 red, 4, 6, 2 red
```

As you can see this smeels like excel formulas, i am unsure how to handle this in c# code however. You can also see i need to use data in the same row, but also get data from other rows that match one propertiy (the items name).

Also if i change the blue value=1 in line 1 to value=2, i want line 1 to read like this:

```
1. living room, ball, 2, 2, even, 6, 8, 2 red
```

and of corse line 4 needs to change to:

```
4. kitchen, ball, 4, 7, 3 red, 6, 8, 2 red
```

Edit: After reading trough your answers and testing my skills to implement your hints, i now have the following code as my class:

```
public class RoomList : ObservableCollection<room>
{
    public RoomList() : base()
    {
        Add(new room() { strRoomName = "living room", strItemname = "ball", intRedItem = 2, intBlueItem = 1 });
        Add(new room() { strRoomName = "sleeping room", strItemname = "bunny", intRedItem = 4, intBlueItem = 1 });
        Add(new room() { strRoomName = "living room", strItemname = "chair", intRedItem = 3, intBlueItem = 2 });
        Add(new room() { strRoomName = "kitchen", strItemname = "ball", intRedItem = 4, intBlueItem = 7 });
        Add(new room() { strRoomName = "garage", strItemname = "chair", intRedItem = 1, intBlueItem = 4 });
    }
}
//rooms
public class room : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string strRoomName { set; get; }
    public string strItemname { set; get; }
    private int _intRed = 0;
    private int _intBlue = 0;
    public int intRedItem
    {
        get { return _intRed; }
        set
        {
            _intRed = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("intRedItem", "strMissing");
        }
    }
    public int intBlueItem
    {
        get { return _intBlue; }
        set
        {
            _intBlue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("intBlueItem", "strMissing");
        }
    }
    public string strMissing
    {
        get
        {
            int missingCount = intRedItem - intBlueItem;
            return missingCount == 0 ? "Even" : missingCount.ToString();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 1: I got the "missing" field working right away, thanks alot for that tip. It really was as easy as i imagined and will be of great use for future projects.

Edit2: Fixed the StackOverflow-Error with adding private dummy variables in my class, see code above.

Edit3: Also fixed the ressource, even tho i swear i used exactly the same code yesterday, but now it is working. Oh well.

**Only one real issue left:**

How do i set a propperty based on OTHER objects properties. The "globalRed" property would need to loop over my list, or the collection, but both don't seem to be an option. At least not like i usually do this in code. "listRooms" does not show up in a properties getter. Also this would need to loop again after new objects get added. I guess then otify method would handle this as well, but how do i loop in the first place?

**And one more question for better understanding:**

Can anyone explain, in simple words, why the above collection is preferable over the list- approach? For all i was able to test they behave identically.

```
//the list-Way
datagridRooms.ItemsSource = listRooms.Where(x=>x.strRoomName == "living room");
//indentical with the collection-way...
datagridRooms.ItemsSource = new RoomList().Where(x=>x.strRoomName== "living room");
```

Comment: winforms wpf asp.net?

Comment: WPF for now, sorry for missing that one. Added to OP.

Comment: A quick style suggestion, name your properties and classes starting with an upper case letter. Name your variables, whether local to a method or a backing store variable to your property as lower case. That gives one a visual indication of scope by seeing the upper case of the letter. For backing store variables I go one step further and give them a prefix of _. So that tells me `_strMissing` is the backing store variable for my Property `StrMissing` which is different from a method's local stack variable of `strMissing`;

Comment: Good suggestion. Already started prefixing my variables with "str", "int" ect. to quickly see what they contain. Already a huge help in bigger projects. Will tr to refine this with your suggestions for even easier readability of my code, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use WPF, then you're going to need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) on your data type classes... your `Room` class. You should also use the [`ObservableCollection<T>` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) for your collections. This enables your UI to update as the data is changed and vice versa.

Now for your '`Excel` formula' fields, you can just create a property for each. You might have to adjust the 'formula' to suit your needs more accurately, but to use your `Missing` field as an example:

```
public string MissingCount
{
    get 
    {
        int missingCount = intRedItem - intBlueItem;
        return missingCount == 0 ? "Even" : missingCount.ToString();
    }
}
```

To make this update in the UI, we need to alert the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event of the change, but because we don't set this property (and that is when we should notify), we have to send notification from the properties that are used in `MissingCount`:

```
public int RedItemCount
{
    get { return redItemCount; }
    set 
    {
        redItemCount = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("RedItemCount", "MissingCount"); 
    }
}

public int BlueItemCount
{
    get { return blueItemCount; }
    set 
    {
        blueItemCount = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("BlueItemCount", "MissingCount"); 
    }
}

public void NotifyPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames) 
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Now whenever your `RedItemCount` or your `BlueItemCount` property values change, the UI will update those values *and* the `MissingCount` value. If you just follow this example for each of your fields, you should be able to get what you want.

---

UPDATE >>>

Ok, so you *seem* to be missing one vital thing. In MVVM, we'd call it a view model. Basically, it's a class that holds *all* of the properties containing the objects that you want to display. So, while you *almost* have that already, you'll need at least one more property:

```
public Room SelectedRoom
{
    get { return selectedRoom; }
    set 
    {
        selectedRoom = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedRoom"); 
        // Calculate new values here
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll still need your collection property:

```
public RoomList RoomList
{
    get { return roomList; }
    set { roomList = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("RoomList"); }
}
```

With these properties, you can `Bind` the collection with the `ItemsSoucre` property and also `Bind` directly with the `SelectedItem` of a collection control (or the `CurrentItem` property of a `DataGrid`... for example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RoomList}" CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedRoom}" ... />
```

Now whenever a new item is selected/focused in the UI, program execution will jump to the `SelectedRoom` setter in the view model where you have access to both the whole collection *and* the selected item and you can calculate anything that you need to.

You will need to set an instance of this view model class as the `DataContext` for the `UserControl`/`Window`, or 'view'.

Comment: Some great hints that really got me going further. Updated my original question with full code now due to me still having some slight errors that i can't seem to fix with the msdn manuals. The idea on how to implement properties without setting them myself in the add-method is pure genius for sure. This alone made the night be worthwhile for me.

Comment: Fixed the error with the overflow, still unsure how to use the collection tho, see edited sample code. Also i can not loop over the properties of my listRooms in the getter, so how would i go about checking OTHER objects wether they contain identical items to add up for the "globalRed" property? Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: Feeling silly, but solved collection issue. Only need a way to loop trough the list or collection in a propertys getter now.

Comment: Hmm, is the code you updated really nessessary? I followed the MSDN page and it seems to be working identically, simply added the following to my xaml:  xmlns:c="clr-namespace:tests"
    <Window.Resources>
       <c:RoomList x:Key="RoomListData"/>
    </Window.Resources>

Comment: No it's not... it depends on your programming style. However, you'll find that adopting the Model, View, View Model paradigm will solve *most* issues that you'll come across with WPF... at least I did. You *can* use your collection as a `Resource`, but then it's more difficult to get hold of the actual collection in the view model, or code behind if you need to manipulate data items or react to changes in the collection.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, slowly learning what all this means. Also learned that i started a projects that is over my head and c# skills ;-)

Comment: Hey, we've all got to start somewhere... it took me a long time before I started using WPF correctly and getting the most out of it. Perseverance is the name of the game,

Answer (score 1):

> extra fields that do not directly show up in my class.

If you can't add more properties to your existing class, one of the best things you can do is create a [Partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class off of the primary class you mentioned. There you can add the logic of the other columns as properties and put in business logic within the property getters/setters to handle the *excel* type operations mentioned.

If a partial class is not available, then create a class which inherits the original class and implements the extended properties needed. *As long as the original class isn't [sealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) preventing that.*

Regardless once done you can use the new modified class to be displayed in the grid.

> Also i want to be able to EDIT the data in the Grid and get updates on related fields.

You will need to make your class adhere to [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). That will allow for changes to occur and be presented to the screen without any direct involvement from you.

> a better way to structure my class.

Do a basic MVVM (Model, View, View-Model approach). It is simply a way to organize your data away from the screen logic.

The view is the page which holds the grid and handles events related to to the GUI. The ViewModel is in charge of *getting data* and frankly just holding data to be bound to by the View. That is where you should put your list of items, and put it into an [Observable Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) which helps when you and or remove items from the list it sends notifications to the GUI (and you if you want to subscribe to such events). The M is models and that is just your class you mentioned earlier. I provide a basic example showing the VM and View on my blog article entitled [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding.](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)

#### Of Note Interfaces

Get into the habit of defining class instances in the terms of C# [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx). If one looks at an interface as a contract to do a specific task, that in itself provides a consistency of development which leads to very extensible code. With an interface one can bring together *disparate* objects into one list and process them in a *consistent* manner. Very powerful in terms of thinking of your code in more than just classes and instances, but at a more higher level of comprehension which leads to more features being able to be added and making the code testable (see [unit testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264975.aspx) in Visual Studio). It takes more work upfront to use interfaces, but it pays off in the future and is something to think about as you learn C# going forward.

Comment: Thanks for those great ideas. Will definitly check all of them out, some even got implemented already, see edit in original question for that. Also i do have full access to all of the code, i just did not know about the possibility to add properties that get autopopulated from a formula and do not have to be typed in myself in the "add" method.